# Key Press (wm_keydown,wparam,lparam) and simulate Enter Key

Tags: keyboard, key, keypress, enter

i didnt understand how to use this method content in a .NetWrapper to inject Keyboard keys (in C#)
I need that when i call the method i could simulate "Enter" Keyboard. (like if i really press on enter key)

:

```
//   msg:
//     The Windows keyboard message (usually WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP and WM_CHAR).
//
//   wparam:
//     The first parameter of the message as intercepted by the window procedure.
//
//   lparam:
//     The second parameter of the message as intercepted by the window procedure.


protected void InjectKeyboardEventWin(int msg, int wparam, int lparam);
```

If i cant use this method to Simulate the "Enter" key is there a way to do it with javascript?

*About the javascript :*

in the HTTP form(where i want simulate the "enter" key) there isn't any "Submit" button.

So the only with to submit data content in the TextBot is with "Enter"

*Ps I cant use JQuery*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where that InjectKeyboardEventWin() method comes from, but the real function in Windows is:

```
VOID WINAPI keybd_event(
  __in  BYTE bVk,
  __in  BYTE bScan,
  __in  DWORD dwFlags,
  __in  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

This will allow you to simulate keypresses to whichever application currently has the focus. You can also simulate mouse events with a similar function. In order to simulate pressing the ENTER key, you will need to call this twice; once for the keydown event and again for the keyup. You can see the details here:

[MSDN doc on keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)